# How to configure react-route with private route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I cannot configure the route correctly. Shop component not renders

Component structure:

[image]

index.tsx:

```
const Index: FC = () => {
  const SignIn = props => (
    <LazyLoad
      component={React.lazy(() => import('./modules/auth/containers/SignIn'))}
      {...props}
    />
  )
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <EmotionThemeProvider>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={Main} />
              <Route path='/signin' component={SignIn} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </EmotionThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

PrivateRoute.tsx:

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      localStorage.getItem('accessToken') ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{ pathname: '/signin', state: { from: props.location } }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
)
```

Main.tsx:

```
const Main: FC = () => (
  <App>
    <Switch>
      {routes.map(route => (
        <Route
          key={route.path}
          path={route.path}
          exact={route.exact}
          component={route.component}
        />
      ))}
    </Switch>
  </App>
)
```

Shop.tsx:

```
const Shop = () => {
  const [, setCollapsed] = useContext(SidebarContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    setCollapsed(true)
  }, [])

  return <div>Shop</div>
}
```

routes.ts:

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/shop',
    key: 'market',
    component: props => (
      <LazyLoad
        component={React.lazy(() => import('./modules/shop/pages/Shop'))}
        {...props}
      />
    ),
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    component: () => <div>main</div>,
    skip: true,
  },
]
```

When I logged in, the main page opens, but after when I go to the shop, it no longer renders.
Where is my mistake? I have tried to remove 'exact' from PrivateRoute, then shop opens, but I got this error:

> Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a
>   component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops

Comment: Can you share code for Shop component.

Comment: @ssk just added